# Web-based .pdf reader with book marks?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any online web based .pdf reader what would allow me to create a bookmark for a page or even paragraph/word so I know what to open start reading next time?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of [web based PDF viewers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Web-based):

- [A.nnotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.nnotate): a web service which views PDF documents as HTML in the browser, with annotation features.
- [Crocodoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodoc): a free web service which allows annotating PDFs and saving them
- [Google Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs): a web service which views PDF documents as JPEG images in the browser
- [Scribd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribd): a web service which renders PDF documents as a Flash widget within a web page
- [vuzit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuzit): a web service which views PDF documents (and 40 others) as HTML in the browser via AJAX.